# Highcharts Server side generation not working on windows 2008 server

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to generate highcharts images using phantomjs on windows 2008 rc2 server, but for some reason the command exits without generating the SVG. The following command is being executed to generate the chart,

```
E://BrandManagement//HighCharts//phantomjs//phantomjs E://BrandManagement//HighCharts//js//highcharts-convert.js -infile C:\Tomcatx64\temp\ILmZ47YS4358686612292944754.json -outfile C:\Tomcatx64\temp\ILmZ47YS4358686612292944754.svg -callback C:\Tomcatx64\temp\OpwX6N8a931179010207236357cb.js -constr  Chart
```

If I execute the command prompt the svg does get created, but not from the java process. If there anything special that needs to be takes care of.

Regards,

Ayush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th problem was with windows permission, tomcat was running as a service, hence probably not able to execute the command.

Went to services>> properties>> security and started running the service as the Administrator logon permission and that did the trick.

Regards,
Ayush